How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1}x([x^{2}+3[x+\sqrt{7}]+2])dx$?
How to integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}x([x^{2}+3[x+\sqrt{7}]+2])dx$$ ? Where $[.]$ denotes Greatest Integer Function.
In this question the main point where I am getting stucked is that we know that $[x+n]=[x]+n$ when $n$ is an integer. But here for my question $\sqrt{7}$ is not an integer. It is an irrational number.
For e.g. If the integral would be like $$\int_{0}^{1}x([x^{2}+3[x+[\sqrt{7}]]+2])dx$$ then we could have took into consideration $[\sqrt{7}]=2$. But the question is not like that.
Secondly I am thinking of integrating by parts. That is the integral will be :
$$x\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+3[x+\sqrt{7}]+2]dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{d}{dx}(x)\int_{0}^{1}[x^{2}+3[x+\sqrt{7}]+2]dx$$
I really can't understand that how to break the portion $[x+\sqrt{7}]$. If I can just get to know this much of help, then I can integrate it easily.
Please help me out with just breaking $[x+\sqrt{7}]$. Rest I can solve by applying Integration By Parts.

$\left[x+\sqrt 7\right]$ is either $2$ or $3$ in that interval, depending on whether $x+\sqrt 7 \ge 3$.

Hint: The given integral is
$$\int_0^1x[x^2]\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^13x[x+\sqrt7]\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^12x\,\mathrm dx$$

Ok. I have understood.

I will follow the method from the first answer.
We have $$\int_0^1x[x^2]+3[x+\sqrt{7}]x+2x\,dx=\int_0^1x[x^2]\,dx+\int_0^13[x+\sqrt{7}]x\,dx+\int_0^12x\,dx$$
The first integral equals to $0$, since $[x^2]=0$ for $0\leq x<1$, but for $x=1$, it is only a point, so the area under it is still $0$.
The second integral: $[x+\sqrt{7}]=2\implies0\leq x<3-\sqrt{7}$; $[x+\sqrt{7}]=3\implies 3-\sqrt{7}\leq x<4-\sqrt{7}$, thus $[x+\sqrt{7}]$ takes values $2$ for $x\in[0,3-\sqrt{7})$ and $3$ for $x\in[3-\sqrt{7},1]$. Then the integral becomes $$\int_0^{3-\sqrt{7}}3\times2x\,dx+\int_{3-\sqrt{7}}^13\times3x\,dx$$The remianing is easy, so I will leave it to you.
